# Rule-based symbology label to map labelling

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, vector, rule-based

How to import values from 'label' in symbology window to showing them as particular labels (QGIS 3.22)? I suppose it can be done with some short, clever expression in labelling window.

[image]

Comment: Are you ok with setting this only once or do you want it to dynamically change based on the rule-based symbology?

Comment: @kowalski yes - I'd be okay with setting this once but it would be much better to see dynamic change in labelling.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve half of it.

Go to the `rule based` symbology, select every rules, right click, copy.

Go to the `label` options, select `rule based`, right click, paste.

Doing this copies every rules, and sets the `description` to the `"label"` value from the symbology.

And here comes the manual, boring task that could be scripted if need be: For every label rule, click and

1. check the `labels` box
2. copy the `description` to the label-`value`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! What's important: my aim was to get name of the column (cat in your example), not the value (1 in your example) - in this way you have to add single brackets.